# Why does the following code for finding out all possible permutations of an integer array work?

Tags: python, permutation, backtracking

```
def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        perm = []

        def dfs(i):
            if len(nums) == 0:
                res.append(perm[:])
                return
            
            for j in range(len(nums)):
                perm.append(nums[j])
                n = nums.pop(j)
                dfs(i+1)
                perm.pop()
                nums.insert(j,n)
       
        dfs(0)
        return res
```

This function gives the correct result for some reason even though it shouldn't as nums[j] should be out of bounds. Can someone explain why this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an `index out of bounds error`, you would have to call `nums[j]`, with `j >= len(nums)`. Here's why that never happens in your code.

You use `j` to identify a location within `nums` three times:

- On first entering the `for` loop, you call `nums[j]` to append to `perm`. So long as `j` is a value between 0 and `len(nums)-1` (because `range(n)` = `(0, 1, 2, ..., n-2, n-1)`), then you can't be out of range. The only way you'd end up being out of range is if the next time you called `nums[j]`, the length of `nums` had changed. Let's see if that happens.
- Your next opportunity to get an `index out of bounds error` is on the next line - `n = nums.pop(j)`. Well there can be no problem here - you were able to grab the value of `nums` at `j` on the previous line, so why shouldn't you be able to `pop` that value out of `nums` now? But now you've mutated `nums`, and if you call `nums[j]` again, AND if `j` is greater than `len(nums) - 2`, you'd be in trouble - let's see if that happens.
- Next, you call `dfs(i+1)`, which opens up a new invocation of `dfs`, and an entirely new `for` loop, with a new `j`, that restarts at `0`, and a new `nums` that's one shorter than it was in the previous function call. If nums is empty, you never enter the for loop, and if nums isn't empty, you enter the for loop with j = 0 - so no risk of being `out of bounds` here.
- The above recursive process continues, restarting the `for` loop with `j = 0` and with `nums` truncated by one, until you get to the bottom of the recursion hole and nums == 0. At this point, you climb back up out of the recursion hole and carry on where you left off - after the last dfs(i+1) call. When you jumped into the recursion hole, you'd just mutated nums, and were in imminent danger of an index out of bounds error...
- The next line (`perm.pop()`) kinda doesn't count in the nums/j saga we're on - so we'll skip past it.
- You then call `nums.insert(j, n)`. `nums.insert(j, n)` places the value assigned to `n` at the index assigned to `j - 1`. e.g: taking a list `lst` with 4 items in it, calling `lst.insert(4, <val>)` would take `<val>` and place it at the end of `nums` - making your `nums.insert(j, n)` equivalent to saying `nums.append(n)`. From the time you popped n out of `nums`, to now, you've basically just shuffled it from where it was to the end of `nums`. You WERE sailing perilously close to an `index out of bounds error`, but you've now undone the mutation you had previously inflicted on `nums`, so as you exit the `for loop`, `nums` is exactly as long as it was when you entered it. Going back to the start of the `for` loop and incrementing `j` before reentering the `for` loop poses no risk to you of an `index out of bounds error`.